# LINQ to XML modifying existing nodes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-xml

I've got `TreeView` that contains nodes and after clicking on one of them, data is loading from file and fills `TextBoxes` etc. I want to prevent creating duplicates, so everytime textBox "title" contains entry that already exist in .xml file, it gets deleted. 
My problem is that after first click on the button that adds entry everything is ok. But after second click (`textBox.Text` value is unchanged, so it'll be a duplicate) node disappears, even if I modify it. And after every double click new child node in treeView is added. I tried to do it by myself, but I ran out of ideas.

button code:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        bool ifDuplicate = doc.Descendants("dog")
                        .Any(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == textBox1.Text);
        if (ifDuplicate == true)
        {
            var xElement = (from q in doc.Elements("dogs").Elements("dog")
                            where q.Attribute("name").Value == textBox1.Text
                            select q);
            foreach (var a in xElement)
                a.Remove();
            doc.Save("test.xml");
            return;
        }

            gender(); //determines in which root node this entry will appear as child node; just comboBox with few exceptions
            TreeViewOperations.SaveTree(treeView1, "test2.xml"); //saving treeView1
            Save("test.xml"); //saving file that contains data form textBoxes etc.
            statusBarUpdate();

    }
```

So my question is: is there any better way to modify existing nodes and deleting duplicates? Can also attach Load method if needed.

**edit:** Save method

> ```
>     private void Save(string filename)
>     {
>         XDocument database = XDocument.Load(filename);
>         XElement dog = new XElement("dog");
>         database.Element("dogs").Add(dog);
>         dog.Add(new XAttribute("name", textBox1.Text));
>         dog.Add(new XElement("breed", comboBox3.Text));
>         dog.Add(new XElement("sex", radioButton3.Checked));
>         database.Save(filename);
>     }
> ```

Comment: Where do you add an entry into the XML?

Comment: I updated question with the code.

Comment: When `ifDuplicate` is `true`. You remove the item without adding a the new one. Is that normal? It does not only prevent duplication, there won't be any element named `textBox1.Text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem comes from the `return` in the `if (ifDuplicate)` block, as it prevent the method to add the new item.

Here is the solution I would use:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");

    // Removes all existing elements
    foreach (XElement xElement in from q in doc.Elements("dogs").Elements("dog")
                                  where q.Attribute("name").Value == textBox1.Text
                                  select q)
        xElement.Remove();

    gender(); //determines in which root node this entry will appear as child node; just comboBox with few exceptions
    TreeViewOperations.SaveTree(treeView1, "test2.xml"); //saving treeView1
    Save("test.xml"); //saving file that contains data form textBoxes etc.
    statusBarUpdate();
}
```

Comment: I can't make your code work, but it doesn't matter, since you were right about "return". I encountered new problem: what if there will be two dogs named "Mike", but different breed. I added next boolean called ifDuplicatedBreed and it works as intended. Tomorrow I'll play more with code and if there will be no errors caused by stated above, I'll mark your post as answer.